# Will htmls inside html work separately from each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wodndoring if I ware to put an html inside another html like so:

```
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
       <html>
        <head></head>
        <body></body>
       </html>
       <html>
        <head></head>
        <body></body>
       </html>
      </body>    
    </html>
```

will each html work separately if I have the same js file included in each of them. I have a form form image preview and I want to include it a few times but to use the same ID's classes and js so I wouldn't have to check on which form I should preform a certain action.

EDITED: But I also need to add extra elements for each form, because the number of forms is based on what the user chooses. I also have a submit button to send data to a database and I need to add these things to each form to know what is being send. So basically the forms are very similar but not identical and adding those extra attributes is easy with php but I can't seem to separate the working from each other and I ware to write a different document for each choice I will need over 100. --> reason for not using iframe

ANSWER: No matter how much work it is changing classes and id's is the most efficient way for problems like this

Comment: you beat me to it @undefined

Comment: But I also need to add extra elements for each form, because the number of forms is based on what the user chooses. I also have a submit button to send data to a database and I need to add these things to each form to know what I'm sending. So basically the forms are very similar but not identical and adding those extra attributes is easy with php but I can't seem to separate the working from each other and I ware to write a different document for each choice I will need over 100.

Answer (score 2):

No, that would be invalid syntax.

However, if you want to have a window within a window, you can use an ***IFrame***.

Try something like this (Keep files in the same directory)

***main.html:***

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <iframe src="cats.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

***cats.html***

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #ff00ff">
    <h1>I like cats!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

you'll see that cats.html is loaded inside main.html

Hope that helps :)

***-- Edit***
If you really really need to keep the same classes, then try something like this:

***main.html:***

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="cat"></input
      <input type="submit">Submit</input>
    </from>
    <script>
      window.setCatFormContent = function(content){$("#cat").val(content)};
    </script>
    <iframe src="cats.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

***cats.html***

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #ff00ff">
    <h1>I like cats!</h1>
    <input type="text" id="cat"></input>
    <button id="sendCat">Kitty Button</button>
    <script>
      $("#sendCat").on("click", function(){
        window.parent.setCatFormContent($("#cat").val()
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: JS from one frame will not interact with another frame unless you really try to make that happen either :)

Comment: I added some edits due to iframe using sorry it wasn't there before

Comment: This looks interesting, but before I try anything is it possible to create an iframe with the code inside like this -> <iframe> ...html... </iframe>, I am trying to ease my job because I want the added data to go trough php...

Comment: Im afraid not. Iframes have to be other files. Could you not change the classes that caused this issue in the first place?

Comment: It's not just the classes, I'm using plupload and it needs to be separate for each form and I have a picture animation that gets element's by classes and it would be a major problem adapting an unknown number of the forms to work separately by changing classes and ID's.

Answer (score 0):

You have to link an external html / php file to your main file as so.

**mainfile.html**

```
<html>

    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
    <iframe src="iframe.html" id="iframeid">Name of iframe</iframe>
    </body>

</html>
```

**iframe.html**

```
<html>

    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form action="action.php" method="post/get">
    </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's not enough just to post some code, you need to explain your answer in details, so everyone easily can understand your suggestion.